# Better way to store inherited class to the file

Tags: c++, inheritance, serialization

This code works, but what is the correct way of doing this?

I mean, how can I eliminate the switch statement in read_in function, or to handle all reading in animal class, or its sub-classes, so my read_in function can be as simple as my write_out function?

I have a `vector<animal*> *animals` filled with cats and generic animals that I need to write/read to/from a file.

I have omitted some code, so the post doesn't get too big...

```
enum class animal_type
{
    GENERIC_ANIMAL,
    CAT
};
```

Suppose I have a class animal

```
class animal
{
    animal_type m_type;
    string m_name;

    virtual void write_binary(ofstream &out)
    {
        out.write((char*)(&m_type), sizeof(m_type)); //first 'animal_type'
        out.write((char*)(&m_type), sizeof(m_type)); //second 'animal_type'
        out.write(m_name.c_str(), m_name.size()+1);
    {

    virtual void read_binary(std::ifstream &in)
    {
        in.read((char*)(&m_type), sizeof(m_type)); //read the second animal type here
        m_name = read_null_string(in);//this function returns next string from input
    }
};
```

and a class that derives from animal

```
class cat : public animal
{
    bool m_is_cute;

    void write_binary(std::ofstream &out)
    {
        animal::write_binary(out);
        out.write((char*)(&m_is_cute), sizeof(m_is_cute));
    }

    void read_binary(std::ifstream &in)
    {
        animal::read_binary(in);
        in.read((char*)(&m_is_cute), sizeof(m_is_cute));

    }
 };
```

I write them to a file like this

```
void write_out(std::ofstream &out, std::vector<animal*> *animals)
{
    int size = animals->size();
    out.write((char*)(&size), sizeof(size));

    for(animal* a : *animals)
    {
        a->write_binary(out);
    }
}
```

And read them from the file like this

```
void read_in(std::ifstream &in, std::vector<animal*> *animals)
{
    animals->clear();
    int size;
    in.read((char*)(&size), sizeof(size));
    for(int i = 0; i< size; ++i)
    {
        animal_type type;
        //read the first 'animal_type' here
        in.read((char*)(&type), sizeof(type));
        animal *a;
        switch(type)
        {
            case(animal_type::GENERIC_ANIMAL):
            a = new animal(in);//this constructor just calls the read_binary method
            break;

            case(animal_type::CAT):
            a = new cat(in);//this constructor just calls the read_binary method
            break;
        }
        animals->push_back(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: consider using `serialization/de-serialization`

Comment: You could have a look at [Boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/serialization/doc/).

Comment: off topic: prefer a reference to `animals` over the pointer here: `void read_in(std::ifstream &in, std::vector<animal*> *animals)`. Among other things, reference protects you from accidentally passing in a bogus pointer. A reference must exist (or you have to play obvious and silly casting games)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one (of many) options:

First, we change `enum class animal_type` to a plain old enum becaysuse we want to use it as an integer. If this is not allowed, leave it `enum class animal_type` and use a `static_cast<size_t>` to convert it later.

```
enum animal_type
{
    GENERIC_ANIMAL = 0, // must be 0. First index in array
    CAT,
    LAST, // must be last. Put no animals after it
    FIRST  = GENERIC_ANIMAL // makes it easy to loop FIRST to LAST
};
```

Then define all of your animals.

Next, build an array of functions that call the appropriate animal constructors. This array must exactly match the enum above. If this is a concern, consider using `std::map` instead.

```
std::function<animal *(std::ifstream &)> animalFactory[] =
{
    [](std::ifstream & in) {return new animal(in);},
    [](std::ifstream & in) {return new cat(in);}
};
```

[Documentation on std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

[Documentation on Lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

Next define exceptions to be thrown should bad things happen. The could be as simple as

```
class Bogus_File_Exception: public std::exception
{
    const char* what() const
    {
        return "File read failed.";
    }
};
```

Finally `read_in` becomes

```
void read_in(std::ifstream &in, std::vector<animal*> & animals) // note the reference
{
    animals.clear();
    int size;
    if (in.read((char*)(&size), sizeof(size))) // testing for successful read
    {
        for(int i = 0; i< size; ++i)
        {
            animal_type type;
            if (in.read((char*)(&type), sizeof(type))) // testing again
            {
                if (type < animal_type::LAST)
                {
                    animals.push_back(animalFactory[type](in));
                }
                else
                {
                    throw Unknown_Animal_Exception();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw Bogus_File_Exception();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw Bogus_File_Exception();
    }
}
```